# Enable/Disable Input based on selection (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<select name="state" class="select" id="state">
    <option value="something">Something</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="province" class="text" id="province" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#state').change(function () {
    if ($('#state Other:selected').text() == "Other"){
        $('#province').attr('disabled', false);
        alert(1);
    } else {
        alert(2);
    }
});
```

Doesn't seem to work. I must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use [`.removeAttr('disabled')`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr) instead of `.attr('disabled', false)`.  Also you should [cache your jQuery selectors](http://blog.seankoole.com/qotd-why-should-you-cache-when-using-jquery).

**Edit:** Thought about this after the fact.  You may want to "empty" the text that had been typed into the field if you are disabling it, so I added a `.val('')`, if you also wanted to hide it, you could add `.hide()` and `.show()` to the two cases.

I put together [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/GpmSs/2) to show you a working version:

```
var $state = $('#state'), $province = $('#province');
$state.change(function () {
    if ($state.val() == 'other') {
        $province.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $province.attr('disabled', 'disabled').val('');
    }
}).trigger('change'); // added trigger to calculate initial state
```

The [`.trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger) will "trigger" a change event, effectively running the function once while you bind it.  This way, the `#province` will be either disabled / enabled based on the state selected at the time the code is run.  Without it, the province would have been available even if the state isn't "other" unless you also added `disabled='disabled'` to the `<input>` tag in your html.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain the trigger a little more. Don't really understand.

Comment: @WmasterJ - Added a bit of an explanation

Comment: What if i want to use the same script for multiple select? Is there a generic one? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to set "disabled" to `true` to actually disable something.  For example, if you want to disable on "Other" and enable on everything else, then I suggest saying:

```
$('#state').change(function () {
    $("#province").attr("disabled", $("#state").val() == "other");
});
```

This uses `$("#province").val()` which is generally the preferred way to get the current value of the selected option from a dropdown in jQuery.  The "disabled" attribute is set to `true` if the value is "other" and false otherwise.