# submit button link based on drop down option selected, opens in new tab

Tags: drop-down-menu, hyperlink, submit

I'm using a script solution I found here, by @clops (clops) that sets the onclick value of a submit button in a form, based on a item selected in a dropdown list. Everything in the script is working as it should, however I would like to open the new window in a new tab on click of the button. Also it would be nice to have the submit button disabled until an option in the list is selected. Any feedback would be helpful. Thanks. 
Current script and HTML is below:

```
                <script>
                function goToNewPage() {
                    if(document.getElementById('target').value){
                        window.location.href = document.getElementById('target').value;
                    }
                }
                </script>
                <form name="dropdown">
                    <select name="selected" id="target" accesskey="E">
                    <option selected>Select...</option>
                    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
                    <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
                    <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.selected)">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing an author can do can choose to open in a new tab instead of a new window.
you could open it in new window as following

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

where the URL is your target form the drop down list

to disable submit button until an option in the list is selected, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597093/enable-disable-input-based-on-selection-jquery)