# how do I suppress certain HTML input fields based on drop down selection?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Hypothetical situation:

I have a form that has 11 fields, fields 1 through 11.

Let's say field 1 is a drop down with 3 values: "A", "B", "C"

How do I use HTML/JavaScript to say that:

if user selects "A", then only fields 2,3,4 are editable (the rest are not)

if user selects "B", then only fields 5,6,7,8 are editable (the rest are not)

if user selects "C", then only fields 9,10,11 are editable (the rest are not.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicat [Enable/Disable Input based on selection (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597093/enable-disable-input-based-on-selection-jquery)

Comment: Note: A mock is generally better than a hypothetical for SO. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/), or [CodePen](http://codepen.io/).

Comment: Use the HTML attribute `disabled` with javascript if statements

Comment: Show us what you have tried thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var selectControl = [['input1', 'input2', 'input3'],
                 ['input4', 'input5', 'input6', 'input7'],
                 ['input8', 'input9', 'input10', 'input11']];

var FormControl = {
init: function () {
    var myform = document.getElementById("myform");
    var myselect = myform.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
    var defaultOption = myselect.value;

    myselect.addEventListener('change', FormControl.changeSelect, false );

    // first load
    FormControl.changeFields( defaultOption );
},

changeSelect: function ( event ) {
    var option = this.value;

    FormControl.changeFields ( option );
},

disableAllInputs: function ( ) {
    var myform = document.getElementById("myform");
    var inputs = myform.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for ( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++ ) 
        inputs[i].disabled = true;
},

changeFields: function ( optionSelected ) {
    var enableInputs = selectControl[optionSelected];

    // disable everything
    FormControl.disableAllInputs();

    // enable only the ones selected
    for ( var i = 0; i < enableInputs.length; i++ ) 
        document.getElementById( enableInputs[i]).disabled = false;
}
};

FormControl.init();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/hKyYk/)

Comment: Quick question: is there a way to change "val" to '' if a particular input is in the not-selected/disabled group?

Comment: rephrase: is there a way to blank out previously entered values if the user switches the option (and thus the field availability)?

Comment: Inside `disableAllInputs` you could add a `inputs[i].value=""` to the `for` loop. This will reset all fields when the users changes the select. [jsFiddle Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/enzoferber/hKyYk/1/)

Comment: awesome thanks! I'm still learning about DOM and JS in general.  Have a great day dude.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach the elements within javascript and do the following:

```
document.getElementById(' ... ').disabled = true;
```

More information can be found on:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input