# unable to enable other select menu based on the value of first select menu

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdown select menu items labelled Connection Mode and Ip Version. Based on value in Connection Mode (static), Ip Version should enable but if I choose "dhcp" in connection mode it should disable Ip Version again on the fly. I referred to this example [Enable/Disable Input based on selection (jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4597093/enable-disable-input-based-on-selection-jquery)

However its not working for my case. The difference is that I am using jquery ui select menu items which are syntactically enabled and disabled differently.

Here is html part:-

```
<label for="cm_0">Connection Mode</label>

        <select id="cm_0">
            <option value="static">static</option>
            <option value="dhcp">DHCP</option>
        </select>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <label for="ipv_0">IP Version</label>

        <select id="ipv_0">
            <option selected>IPv4</option>
            <option>IPv6</option>
        </select>
```

This is jquery part:-

```
$("#cm_0,#cm_1,#ipv_0,#ipv_1").selectmenu({
        width:153,
        disabled:true
    });

/*based on the stackoverflow link i shared*/
$("#cm_0").change(function(){
    if($("#cm_0").val() === "static") {
        $("#ipv_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);
        console.log("static chosen");
    }
    else{
        $("#ipv_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
    }
    }).trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `selectmenuchange` event:

```js
$("#cm_0").selectmenu({
  width:153,
});

$("#ipv_0").selectmenu({
  width:153,
  disabled:true
});

$("#cm_0").on("selectmenuchange", function(){
  if($("#cm_0").val() === "static") {
    $("#ipv_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",false);
  }
  else{
    $("#ipv_0").selectmenu("option","disabled",true);
  }
}).trigger('selectmenuchange');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<label for="cm_0">Connection Mode</label>

        <select id="cm_0">
            <option value="static">static</option>
            <option value="dhcp">DHCP</option>
        </select>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <label for="ipv_0">IP Version</label>

        <select id="ipv_0">
            <option selected>IPv4</option>
            <option>IPv6</option>
        </select>
```